# Calculate the frequency of similar rows but keeping the same size of dataframe

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have a data frame with repeated rows and i have a function that calculate the frequency of similar rows.
Here is my sample

```
#############
###Sample####
#############

ID=seq(from=1,to=12,by=1)
var1=c(rep("a",12))
var2=c(rep("b",12))
var3=c("c","c","b","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","k")
df=data.frame(ID,var1,var2,var3)

   ID var1 var2 var3
1   1    a    b    c
2   2    a    b    c
3   3    a    b    b
4   4    a    b    d
5   5    a    b    e
6   6    a    b    f
7   7    a    b    g
8   8    a    b    h
9   9    a    b    i
10 10    a    b    j
11 11    a    b    k
12 12    a    b    k

###############
# function ####
###############

freq.f<- function(data){
  vari=colnames(data[2:ncol(data)])
  data  %>%     
    dplyr:: count(!!! rlang::syms(vari))  %>%
    mutate(frequency = n/sum(n))
  
}

# current output
freq.f(df)
   var1 var2 var3 n  frequency
1     a    b    b 1 0.08333333
2     a    b    c 2 0.16666667
3     a    b    d 1 0.08333333
4     a    b    e 1 0.08333333
5     a    b    f 1 0.08333333
6     a    b    g 1 0.08333333
7     a    b    h 1 0.08333333
8     a    b    i 1 0.08333333
9     a    b    j 1 0.08333333
10    a    b    k 2 0.16666667
```

What i want is calculating this frequency but keeping all my records because my ID are different persons even if they have the same row information, and i also want to be able to print the ID in my output to keep track of the individuals. So the desired output is

```
# desired output

   ID var1 var2 var3 n  freq
1   1    a    b    c 2  0.16666667
2   2    a    b    c 2  0.16666667
3   3    a    b    b 1  0.08333333
4   4    a    b    d 1  0.08333333
5   5    a    b    e 1  0.08333333
6   6    a    b    f 1  0.08333333
7   7    a    b    g 1  0.08333333
8   8    a    b    h 1  0.08333333
9   9    a    b    i 1  0.08333333
10 10    a    b    j 1  0.08333333
11 11    a    b    k 2  0.16666667
12 12    a    b    k 2  0.16666667
```

I really looked in almost every post in SO about frequency but can not find my answer. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a join within your function provides expected results.

```
freq.f<- function(data){
  vari=colnames(data[2:ncol(data)])
  inner_join(data, data  %>%     ##this is the new line
    dplyr:: count(!!! rlang::syms(vari))  %>%
    mutate(frequency = n/sum(n)))
}
freq.f(df)

   ID var1 var2 var3 n  frequency
1   1    a    b    c 2 0.16666667
2   2    a    b    c 2 0.16666667
3   3    a    b    b 1 0.08333333
4   4    a    b    d 1 0.08333333
5   5    a    b    e 1 0.08333333
6   6    a    b    f 1 0.08333333
7   7    a    b    g 1 0.08333333
8   8    a    b    h 1 0.08333333
9   9    a    b    i 1 0.08333333
10 10    a    b    j 1 0.08333333
11 11    a    b    k 2 0.16666667
12 12    a    b    k 2 0.16666667
```

Comment: Thank you @Cole i did not see it at all that i can merge to get the answer! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

@mathematical.coffee's idea can be written in `dplyr` as well.

```
library(dplyr)

freq.f<- function(data){

  data  %>%     
    group_by(across(-1)) %>%
    #If you are on dplyr < 1.0.0 use group_by_at
    #group_by_at(-1) %>%
    mutate(frequency = n()/nrow(.))
}

freq.f(df)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   var1, var2, var3 [10]
#      ID var1  var2  var3  frequency
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     1 a     b     c     0.167 
# 2     2 a     b     c     0.167 
# 3     3 a     b     b     0.0833
# 4     4 a     b     d     0.0833
# 5     5 a     b     e     0.0833
# 6     6 a     b     f     0.0833
# 7     7 a     b     g     0.0833
# 8     8 a     b     h     0.0833
# 9     9 a     b     i     0.0833
#10    10 a     b     j     0.0833
#11    11 a     b     k     0.167 
#12    12 a     b     k     0.167
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are amenable to using `data.table` rather than dplyr there is a very natural syntax:

```
# convert df to data.table
dt = data.table(df)

# for each unique (var1, var2, var3), calculate the frequency 
# by=.(var1, var2, var3) does the grouping
# .N is the number of rows in the group
# freq := .... makes a new column called 'freq' and stores the associated value.
> dt[, freq := .N/nrow(dt), by=.(var1, var2, var3)]
> dt
       ID   var1   var2   var3       freq
    <num> <char> <char> <char>      <num>
 1:     1      a      b      c 0.16666667
 2:     2      a      b      c 0.16666667
 3:     3      a      b      b 0.08333333
 4:     4      a      b      d 0.08333333
 5:     5      a      b      e 0.08333333
 6:     6      a      b      f 0.08333333
 7:     7      a      b      g 0.08333333
 8:     8      a      b      h 0.08333333
 9:     9      a      b      i 0.08333333
10:    10      a      b      j 0.08333333
11:    11      a      b      k 0.16666667
12:    12      a      b      k 0.16666667
```

Or can replace `by=.(var1, var2, var3)` with `by=vari` if you want to get those columns programmatically.

Comment: Thank you @mathematical.coffe for your answer! it is a different way of getting the answer but i would have to stick to `dplyr`.